# Scroll jump on page refresh with fragment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with comments. Let's call it the `article page`. Now, when I add a new comment, I need to reload this page since I need to see an added comment. I can't (and don't want to) inject it directly into DOM since calculating its position may be quite complex.

I'm sending an AJAX request, and in response I get:

- comment id
- url of the `article page`

Then I use it to construct URL in form `myawesomewebsite.com/articlePage/{{articleId}}#{{commentId}}`. So basically, I refresh current page, and additionally I add fragment part to it so that on the page load I can see my new comment.

I use

- `window.location = articlePageURL + "#" + commentId` to construct the URL
- and `window.location.reload(true)` to get "new" page with attached new comment

The problem is that after automatic scroll to `div` with comment, browser skips back to the position I was on previous page (its the same page before refreshing).

Is there any way I can turn off second page jump?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve what I wanted.

Instead of relying on autoscroll to id given in hash fragment of URL, i scroll to this element myself. The key is to use `scrollTop` css attribute on body element and combine it with `animate` function.

Not only it works as I expected but it gives much better UX.